# Error while compiling MOV instruction in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm64, mov, armv8, immediate-operand

I am using RVDS6_13 compiler and my processor is Cortex X1 (HERA). For a test where I need to do a bit of assembly language programming, I am getting below error in compilation:

**Error: A1616E: Instruction, offset, immediate or register combination is not supported by the current instruction set
9 00000000  MOV x28,0xD02E7F30**

Basically I need to load 0xB41138A4 to address location 0xD02E7F30 and below is my code:

```
 MOV  x28,0xD02E7F30  
 STR  x28,0xB41138A4
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need something like `mov w28, 0x7F30`, `movk w28, 0xD02E, lsl 16`? Also, that `STR` doesn't look like ARM assembly to me. Typically you'd load the address into a register first, and then use `[reg]` as the second operand (where `reg` is the register you placed the address in).

Comment: Thank you Michael, actually I was thinking if x28, x29 are 32 bit registers, then why I cannot load the address and data directly with 32 bit word and then through STR instruction I will load the address with the data. But seems though these are 32 bit registers, I have to split it into two 16 bit operations and left shift as you suggested to effectively get a 32 bit operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the value with the special “literal pool” `LDR` instruction and the partial address (everything but the low 12 bits) with the `ADRP` instruction.  Then store with the remaining address bits as a displacement:

```
LDR w28, =0xD02E7F30
ADRP x29, 0xB4113000
STR w28, [x29, 0x8A4]
```

(I have changed your store to be a 32 bit store as I assume you've mistakingly used a 64 bit store)

Instead of the `ldr w28, =...` instruction you can also use a `MOVZ`/`MOVK` pair to get rid of the literal pool load:

```
MOVZ w28, 0x7F30, LSL #0
MOVK w28, 0xD02E, LSL #16
ADRP x29, 0xB4113000
STR w28, [x29, 0x8A4]
```

If your binary is supposed to be position independent, you'll also have to load the address using `LDR w29, =...` or `MOVZ`/`MOVK` as `ADRP` loads a `PC`-relative address:

```
MOVZ w28, 0x7F30, LSL #0
MOVK w28, 0xD02E, LSL #16
MOVZ x29, 0x38A4, LSL #0
MOVK x29, 0XB411, LSL #16
STR w28, [x29]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the last solution and at least got an error free code.